# Handling UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet, uiactionsheetdelegate

In my application i should have a common `UINavigationBar` to hold with 3 `UIBarButton` items with its actions. So, instead of writting code in every ViewControllers, i have decided to create on `BaseViewController` which can be subclass to my application ViewControllers,

- [BaseViewController.h](https://gist.github.com/spraveenk/daa040734622363db7b6)
- [BaseViewController.m](https://gist.github.com/spraveenk/631b7c2b8e3d0afed7a0)

After, implementing this `UINavigationBar` showing with its items fine. In one of my bar button item in BaseVC will present `UIActionSheet` and when select something from this, need to get selected index from BaseVC to MainVC. So, i have created a custom protocol method to pass the selected action sheet index to my MainVC from BaseVC.

## MainVC == FirstViewController

- [FirstViewController.h](https://gist.github.com/spraveenk/18c0c8116e0250ba8c2d)
- [FirstViewController.m](https://gist.github.com/spraveenk/e94a1970c6550d04414e)

This scenario also getting works. But, if i add one or more `UIActionSheet` in my FirstVC its getting called and works fine. But, it disables the BaseVC's Actionsheet delegate call. It means, it is not allowing to call the delegate on BaseVC,

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

Above delegate not fired in BaseVC. How to handle both `UIActionSheet` from different VC.

Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to invoke it manually using logic in your FirstViewController method call.  You can do this by calling `[super actionSheet:actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex]` when you know the call is meant to be handled by the BaseVC.